# Sharing the folder makes the website throw error 500 in iis 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, web-hosting, iis-7.5

I am setting up a simple site which shall contain some static file and I want to enable directory browsing plus this site should be available to all.

1. Whenever I enable directory
   browsing it creates a web.config
   file, (I don't want it).  now I can 
   browse the site. so far OK.
2. I share the folder to allow access to a
   group, now this site stops working and
   throws 500 error.

Server is windows 2008 R2, IIS 7.5

Answer (score 1):

It got solved however I am not sure it will work in all scenarios because there is no direct correlation.

I granted read & execute rights to Server/IIS_IUSERS and it resolved the problem.